# How to Link Title field to another field which links to an external site?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I have a collection of news stories whose default linkable values (titleField and fullStoryHereField) link to their specific nodes. 
However if the user wants to link to an external site, the user can specify a link in the fullStoryHereField (in where the news story is entered) and now the fullStoryHereField link goes to the external site while the rest go to their specific nodes…Good

Now here is what I want my titleField to do once clicked, either go to: (a) their specific node if no external link is given or (b) the external link that was given.

How can I accomplish that?

I want to keep my fields displayed in a certain order too:

```
    Title
    Teaser
    Full Story Here
```

I’ve tried a whole array of things, including trying to add different fields and link them to fullStoryHereField and mark them as hidden, however, I cannot link the new field back to my titleField in the order I want things displayed.

I’m trying to avoid editing the php/tpl files as I want to accomplish this in the Drupal application

Comment: You have Display Suite installed right? You could add a code field replacing your title field with the custom DS text format for your biew mode. Not the most beautiful solution but a widely used approach ;)